# error 255 trying to install laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I've started getting this error 
"

> php artisan optimize
>   Script php artisan optimize handling the post-install-cmd even returned with error code 255
>   "

when trying to install a fresh project v5.3 of laravel today. The install worked fine just yesterday, and it doesn't give me that error if i try to install laravel v5.2.

Does anyone know of/how to fix this? :o

Comment: how you are installing because 5.3 is now live and it is not giving any kind of such error for me. i am working with it. try to clear composer cache

Answer (score 0):

Check your php version
And do a composer update

Tell us if error still showing.

Comment: Got the lastest version on both of the computers and as I mentioned, it worked fine yesterday when i made a new laravel project.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the 255 error when trying install 5.2. If I specify 5.2.* then it installs fine. But if I just use 5.2 then I get the 255 error.